# Adding a line to a matplotlib scatterplot based on a slope

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot built from a DataFrame - it shows a correlation of two variables - Length and Age

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = DataFrame (......)
plt.title ('Fish Length vs Age')
plt.xlabel('Length')
plt.ylabel('Age (days)')
plt.scatter(df['length'],df['age'])
```

[image]

Now i want to add a line with a given slope of **0.88** to this scatter plot. How do i do this?

P.S. All examples i managed to find use points and not slopes to draw the line

**UPDATE**. I re-read the theory - and it turned out that the fact that the correlation coefficient should be plotted against the data points was made up by me :) Partially because of this image in my head [image]

However i still am confused by the line - plotting capabilities of matplotlib

Comment: You can have a Pearson correlation coefficient of 0.88 for an infinite number of lines - the r value (PCC) doesn't tell you the slope of the line it tells you how far the data points lie from that "line of best fit". Can you edit your question to clarify what you'd like the _slope_ to be?

Comment: @KirstieJane I've updated the question :)

Comment: @iX3 it doesn't make sense to link to the Pearson correlation coefficient in the question. The slope has nothing to do with it and the reference should be deleted.

Comment: @KirstieJane, sorry about that. It looked like someone was changing the OP's question w/o any explanation; that's why I rejected the deletion. I will attempt to correct that now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on @JinxunLi's answer you just want to add in a line connecting two points.

These two points have x and y coordinates so for the two points you'll have four numbers: `x_0`, `y_0`, `x_1`, `y_1`.

Let's assume you want the x coordinates of those two points to span the x axis so you're going to set `x_0` and `x_1` manually:

```
x_0 = 0
x_1 = 5000
```

Alternatively you can just take the minimum and maximum values from the axis:

```
x_min, x_max = ax.get_xlim()
x_0 = x_min
x_1 = x_max
```

You define the slope of a line as `increase in y / increase in x` which would be:

```
slope = (y_1 - y_0) / (x_1 - x_0)
```

And this can rearrange to:

```
(y_1 - y_0) = slope * (x_1 - x_0)
```

There are an infinite number of parallel lines with this slope so we'll have to set one of the points to start off with. For this example let's assume you want the line to go through the origin `(0,0)`

```
x_0 = 0 # We already know this as it was set earlier
y_0 = 0
```

Now you can rearrange the formula for `y_1` as:

```
y_1 = slope * (x_1 - x_0) + y_0
```

If you know you want the slope to be 0.88 then you can calculate the y position of the other point:

```
y_1 = 0.88 * (5000 - 0) + 0
```

For the data you've provided in the question a line with slope 0.88 will fly off the top of the y axis very quickly (`y_1 = 4400` in the example above).

In the example below I've put in a line with slope = 0.03.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# simulate some artificial data
# =====================================
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'Age' : np.random.rand(25) * 160 } )

df['Length'] = df['Age'] * 0.88 + np.random.rand(25) * 5000

# plot those data points
# ==============================
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['Length'], df['Age'])

# Now add on a line with a fixed slope of 0.03
slope = 0.03

# A line with a fixed slope can intercept the axis
# anywhere so we're going to have it go through 0,0
x_0 = 0
y_0 = 0

# And we'll have the line stop at x = 5000
x_1 = 5000
y_1 = slope (x_1 - x_0) + y_0

# Draw these two points with big triangles to make it clear
# where they lie
ax.scatter([x_0, x_1], [y_0, y_1], marker='^', s=150, c='r')

# And now connect them
ax.plot([x_0, x_1], [y_0, y_1], c='r')    

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just realized that you need to limit a line in matplotlib - id doesnt have a notion of 'infinity'// thanks again

Answer (score 9):

The correlation coefficient won't give the slope of the regression line, because your data are in different scales. If you would like to plot scatter with regression line, I would recommend to do it in `seaborn` with a minimum lines of codes.

To install `seaborn`,

```
pip install seaborn
```

Code example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# simulate some artificial data
# =====================================
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.multivariate_normal([10, 100], [[100, 800], [800, 10000]], size=100), columns=['X', 'Y'])

df

# plot 
# ====================================
sns.set_style('ticks')
sns.regplot(df.X, df.Y, ci=None)
sns.despine()
```

[image]

### Edit:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# simulate some artificial data
# =====================================
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.multivariate_normal([10, 100], [[100, 800], [800, 10000]], size=100), columns=['X', 'Y'])


# plot
# ==============================
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df.X, df.Y)

# need a slope and c to fix the position of line
slope = 10
c = -100

x_min, x_max = ax.get_xlim()
y_min, y_max = c, c + slope*(x_max-x_min)
ax.plot([x_min, x_max], [y_min, y_max])
ax.set_xlim([x_min, x_max])
```

[image]

Comment: No no no!! :) I am not plotting the regression line yet :)  I just want to plot that single line with a given slope for now :) Could you please help with doing it using the matplotlib only?

Comment: @Dennis a line with correlation coefficient as slope is meaningless in the context of a scatter plot, because your x-y scale doesn't match. To see what I mean, try draw y = c + 0.88x on your scatter plot, when x increase from 1000 to 2000, y should increase by 880. And what's your y-scale? `[0,160]` doesn't fit. The regression slope gives `correlation * sigma_y / sigma_x` which accounts for such scaling issue.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and am very grateful to you for such an explicit explanation! BUT :) What if i rephrased my question "Ho do i draw a line with a given slope in matplotlib?" Could you please help me with this simple question forgetting about regression and correlation for a second? :) Pleeeease

Comment: @Dennis Ok, I've edited the answer to use `.plot` with two points to plot a line.